# Why is the sum of X-ray's of permutations linearly distributed?

Tags: co.combinatorics, probability-distributions, permutations

Let $\mathfrak{S}_n$ be the set of permutations, on $\{1,2,\dots,n\}$, and the binary matrix $A$ is the corresponding permutation matrix for element $\pi\in\mathfrak{S}_n$.

Given a permutation matrix $A$ for $\pi\in\mathfrak{S}_n$, the diagonal [*$X$-ray sequence*](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0506334.pdf) of permutation matrix $A=(a_{ij})$ is defined as:
$X(A)=x(1)x(2)\cdots x(2n-1)$ where $x(k)=\sum_{i+j=k+1}a_{ij}$.

Let us define the distribution $f(n)$ over all permutations in $\mathfrak{S}_n$ as
$f(n)=\sum_{\pi\in\mathfrak{S}_n}X_{\pi}$. The sum is the vector sum of all $X$ vectors.

Experimentally, I obtained this characterization for ($\mathfrak{S}_{12}$):

[image]

> How can we analytically drive this distribution? Why is it linear?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Let $A$ be any set of cells in the $n\times n$ matrix grid with $\#A=k$. Consider the sum over all permutation matrices in $\mathfrak{S}_n$ of all the entries in $A$. By ``linearity of expectation'' (or just by exchanging the order of summation of two finite sums) we may instead consider the sum, over all cells in $A$, of the sum over all permutation matrices of the entry in that cell. By symmetry, for each of these cells the sum is $\frac{1}{n}\cdot n!$, so the overall sum is $\frac{k}{n}\cdot n!$.

Now consider the slices $i+j=k+1$ which define the X-ray of a permutation as sets of cells of the $n\times n$ grid. The sizes of slices are $1,2,\ldots,n$ up to the $n$th slice (the anti-main diagonal), and then back down $n-1,n-2,\ldots,1$ afterward. With the preceding paragraph, this explains the linearity of the sums you observed.

Comment: Nice demonstration of the power of *linearity of expectations*.